# Newton's Third Law Intuition Help

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

The problem states the following:

A 1,000 Kg car pushes a 2,000 Kg truck that has a dead battery. When the driver steps on the accelerator, the drive wheels of the car push against the ground with a force of 4,500 N. Rolling friction can be neglected.

A. What is the magnitude of the force of the car on the truck (answer 3,000 N)

B. What is the magnitude of the force of the truck on the car (answer 3,000 N)

It seems like a straight-forward problem yet how they got the answer i do not understand. Does the 4,500 N of the wheel represent the force that is being applied to both of the cars?

Calling car = b and truck = c  also calling $f_R$ the resisting force of the truck would i do the following?

$(F_{nat})_x: (m_c+m_b)a = 4500 \therefore$

$a=1.5$

using this can i say that the force in the positive x direction due to the car is $a m_b = 1500N$ and the force due to the truck in the positive x direction is $a m_c = 3000 N$? Would this be what they mean?

Comment: yes, and if you assume that the acceleration of both is the same, it is not difficult to find the contact force between the vehicles. Just write the equations for the joint system and for the two individual systems. You'll get enough equations to calculate the unknown contact force

Comment: @julianfernandez like what i edited above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation for the joint system is correct. The ones for the individual vehicles is not. You will have, for the car, $a m_b = F_ {cont}$ ($F_{cont}$ being the contact force applied to the car by the truck) which you do not yet know, and, for the truck: $a m_c = 4500-F_{cont}$ (the two forces that act on the truck). From the last two equations you can get $F_{cont}$

Comment: thats what i mean by me question, $f_{cont} = 1,500$ then which was $a m_B$ since $(m_c+m_b)a = 4500$ then $ a = 1.5$ so then $a m_b = 1500$ = positive force in x direction of car. right? therefore the magnitude of the force is $|1500-4500| = 3000 N$

For the truck $a m_c = 4500 - F_{cont}$ therefore $a m_c = 3000 N$

Comment: yes you are correct, I missed that you already had subtracted the contact force. Good job!

Comment: Just one suggestion, If you are taking an exam, you better write the equations explicitly instead of doing it in your mind, it will be easier for your teacher and there will be less chance that he thinks you copied the answer from somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

From a free body diagram of car,
$$4,500-F_\textrm{cont}=m_b\,a.$$ 
From a free body diagram of truck,
$$F_\textrm{cont}=m_c\,a\quad\implies\quad a=\frac{F_\textrm{cont}}{m_c}\cdot$$
Putting this into the first equation and we get the answer.